# Automating the Process of Renaming the Column Names in Multiple Excel Sheets

Tags: sql, vba, excel, unix

I have a requirement from the client in which they want us to rename the column  from multiple excel sheets which are present in the same directory.
There are 70+ excel reports and we are not sure that the particular column is present in which excel file. So every time they ask us to change, all the time we have to drill down all the excel sheets to find out the changes required which is really time consuming.

I thought of automating the process. Since all the files are present under the same directory, can't we use a MACRO,BATCH/UNIX SCRIPTS or any other way by which we can traverse the entire directory and make those changes by performing a find and replace thing.

So my first question is, if this is feasible ? If yes, then can anyone suggest/advice how to work around on this process ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes you can do that with VBA and there are plenty of similar questions here on SO to get you started.

Comment: Yeah I saw, but they are only to update the multiple sheets within an excel workbook. I want it to update  column names in multiple excel files within a directory

Comment: There are [many answered questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel-vba%5D+looping+through+excel+files) that deal with looping through multiple excel books. Try and combine solutions, and come back with whatever code you have written from it!

Comment: The whole point of this site is not to provide fully fleshed-out solutions to your specific problem (though you occasionally will get lucky and find one), but to *help you code your own solution*

Answer (score 0):

I can't take full credit for the below as this is a patchwork of code I have used over the years. This is how I would go about it personally:

1. Manually make a copy of the files to change and place them in a folder (keep the originals safe!)
2. Let the code open each file and change it
3. Code will save a copy in a different 'done' folder

The example below loops through each Excel file and moves it from the 'to-do' folder to the 'done' folder once it has changed the cell "A1" to "Hello World". When the 'to-do' folder is empty the code stops.

You'll need to change the file paths for this to work.

```
Sub Example()

Dim FolderPath As String, FilePath As String, FileCount As Integer
Dim objExcelApp As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim SaveName As String

    FolderPath = "C:\Users\********\Desktop\To Do\"
    NewFolderPath = "C:\Users\********\Desktop\Done\"
    FilePath = FolderPath & "*.xl??"
    FileName = Dir(FilePath)

ChangeNextFile:

    FileCount = 0

    'count how many files in "files to be changed" folder
    Do While FileName <> ""
        FileCount = FileCount + 1
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    'if there are no files left end the code
    If FileCount = 0 Then GoTo FinishedLoadingFiles

    'choose the first file to change
    FileName = Dir(FilePath)
    Debug.Print FileName

        'create an instance of Excel
        Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        With objExcelApp
            .Visible = False
            .DisplayAlerts = False
        End With
        'opens the excel file in the background
        objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open FileName:=FolderPath & FileName, UpdateLinks:=False
        Set wb = objExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook
        objExcelApp.ActiveWindow.Activate
        'changes cell "A1" to say "hellow world"
        wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Hello World"
        'saves the file in the done pile
        wb.saveas NewFolderPath & FileName '& ".xlsb"
        'closes excel
        With objExcelApp
            .DisplayAlerts = True
        End With
        wb.Close
        objExcelApp.Quit
        Set wb = Nothing
        Set objExcelApp = Nothing

    'deletes the original file. New file has been saved in the new folder
    Kill FolderPath & FileName

    GoTo ChangeNextFile

FinishedLoadingFiles:

MsgBox "All done"

End Sub
```